# After run and close i cannot resize my gui anymore

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder

I have been out for a while, not that i am a good programmer.
But when i made an application window in eclipse (new--- other---WindowBuilder--swing designer--application window)

this is the code it generates

```html
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AddTournamentToRankingGUI {

 private JFrame frame;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     AddTournamentToRankingGUI window = new AddTournamentToRankingGUI();
     window.frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }

 public AddTournamentToRankingGUI() {
  initialize();
 }

 private void initialize() {
  frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setBounds(100, 100, 680, 814);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
  }
```

I tried to resize in eclipse, no problem. then i hit run and hit the close button and tried to resize the GUI in eclipse again.
This is where i cannot resize the window. only after a restart i can resize it in eclipse until i run the app again.

I have tried to add code to complete exit the application, but same result.
This is the code i used

```html
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/*Some piece of code*/
frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, 
            "Are you sure you want to close this window?", "Close Window?", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I havent used any other cose, only resize the gui, run the app, tried resizing and i was failing. i will add the extra code i added to try to resolve it, but it had the same result.

Comment: Let me put it this way: unless you can give us a code sample (25 lines max) which demonstrates this, we cannot help you.

Comment: added the code i used, hopefully this is what you ment. As nothing else i have done. except searching for this problem ofcourse.

Comment: How and when are you attempting to resize the frame?

Comment: I have tried resizing with success before i run the app, with drag and drop in the GUI window, after run this did not work anymore.

Comment: Are you trying to resize it while the dialog is open?  If so, you cannot do that.

Comment: Nope, i have closed the app, then i try to resize the window. that part does not work

Comment: That makes no sense.  If the app is closed, there should be no window.

Comment: oke, we are misscommunicating i see,   the resizing is in the eclipse GUI screen, not the app itself as it is indeed closed.    all the resizing i mention is in eclipse.

Comment: If you want to answer your question, post a separate answer - don't add "Solved" to the title.

Comment: thank you, i was searching for a solved button, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid... i thought the move cursor was the resize cursor, so that is why it did not work obviously..